# microsoft emotion api multiple images PYTHON 2.7

Tags: python, api, azure, emotion

I am currently using Microsoft Azure Emotion API to look at emotion of certain images. Although the sample code works (Python 2.7) , I want this to be more than one image.

I will have a directory (URL) that has 100 images in, labelled image1, image2, image3.

What I am looking for is a change of the code to give an average rating/score for the images that it has looped around.

The code I have is:

```
import httplib, urllib, base64

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'MY KEY HERE',
}

params = urllib.urlencode({
})

body = "{ 'url': 'https://assets.mubi.com/images/notebook/post_images/22267/images-w1400.jpg?1474980339' }"

try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize?%s" % params, body, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

I am thinking a while loop:

```
for x in range (0,100):
```

and change the URL: to the path with (x) 
But I can't get this to work.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks, Nathan.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you actually want? As I know,the result of calling the emotion API is facerectangle and scores.You want to get the facerectangle and scores averages of 100 images directly through the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment , I presume you want to get the facerectangle and scores averages of 100 images.
Per my experience, we can not get the result you want through the Emotion API directly .

I suggest you using the loop invoke API to summarize the results ,then calculate the average result.

You could refer to the code as below I already tested successfully.

```
import httplib, urllib, base64, json

headers = {
    # Request headers. Replace the placeholder key below with your subscription key.
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'YOUR KEY',
}

params = urllib.urlencode({
})

widthTotal = 0
topTotal = 0
leftTotal = 0
heightTotal = 0
sadnessTotal = 0
neutralTotal = 0
contemptTotal = 0
disgustTotal = 0
angerTotal = 0
surpriseTotal = 0
fearTotal = 0
happinessTotal = 0

count = 100

try:
    for x in range(0, count):
        # Replace the example URL below with the URL of the image you want to analyze.
        body = "{ 'url': 'https://assets.mubi.com/images/notebook/post_images/22267/images-w1400.jpg?1474980339' }"

        # NOTE: You must use the same region in your REST call as you used to obtain your subscription keys.
        #   For example, if you obtained your subscription keys from westcentralus, replace "westus" in the
        #   URL below with "westcentralus".
        conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
        conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize?%s" % params, body, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        data = response.read()
        # print(data)

        Arr = json.loads(data, encoding='utf-8')
        # print Arr[0].values()[0]
        # print Arr[0].values()[1]
        # print Arr[0].values()[0]["width"]
        widthTotal += Arr[0].values()[0]["width"]
        topTotal += Arr[0].values()[0]["top"]
        leftTotal += Arr[0].values()[0]["height"]
        heightTotal += Arr[0].values()[0]["height"]
        sadnessTotal += Arr[0].values()[1]["sadness"]
        neutralTotal += Arr[0].values()[1]["neutral"]
        contemptTotal += Arr[0].values()[1]["contempt"]
        disgustTotal += Arr[0].values()[1]["disgust"]
        angerTotal += Arr[0].values()[1]["anger"]
        surpriseTotal += Arr[0].values()[1]["surprise"]
        fearTotal += Arr[0].values()[1]["fear"]
        happinessTotal += Arr[0].values()[1]["happiness"]

        conn.close()

except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

print "width avg: " + str(widthTotal / count)
print "top avg: " + str(topTotal / count)
print "left avg: " + str(leftTotal / count)
print "heigh avg: " + str(heightTotal / count)
print "sadness avg: " + str(sadnessTotal / count)
print "neutral avg: " + str(neutralTotal / count)
print "contempt avg: " + str(contemptTotal / count)
print "disgust avg: " + str(disgustTotal / count)
print "anger avg: " + str(angerTotal / count)
print "surprise avg: " + str(surpriseTotal / count)
print "fear avg: " + str(fearTotal / count)
print "happiness avg: " + str(happinessTotal / count)
```

***Print Output:***

[image]

Hope it helps you.